# doctrine odm, find document where id is not object id

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my mongodb I have a collection, where the id-field is not an object-Id
I don't know why it was built like that and I can't change it from scratch cause there's probably a lot of software already using this pattern.

However, this is how such Icecream document looks like:

```
{
   "_id": "52d0283ae4b01db941dd763b",
   "insertDate": ISODate("2014-01-10T17:04:58.617Z"),
   "language": "en",
   "profile": ObjectId("50e577602b5e05e74b38a6c8"),
   "related": ObjectId("516c0061975a299edc44b419"),
   "survey": ObjectId("516c0061975a299edc44b409"),
   "version": NumberInt(0) 
}
```

and with mongoshell I can find it like:

```
 db.icecream.find({"_id":"52d0283ae4b01db941dd763b"})
```

instead of using:

```
 db.icecream.find({"_id":ObjectId("52d0283ae4b01db941dd763b")})
```

so I tried a lot of queries to find it, but doctrine odm always does not the correct query, here's my latest try:

```
  return $this->mongo->getManager()
    ->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Icecream')
    ->findOneBy(array('_id' => (string)$answerId));
```

which returns

```
   doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"find":true,"query":{"_id":{"$id":"52ced410e4b0fcc3da3a0c8b"}},"fields":[],"db":"myIcecreamDb","collection":"icecream"} [] []
```

anybody any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your own string _id (a NOT MongoId object), you may want to use the 'strategy' proprerty of Id.

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document */
class MyPersistentClass
{
    /** @ODM\Id(strategy="NONE") */
    private $id;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }    
}
```

You can see more options in the docs here:
http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping-identifiers

Comment: This worked when I created an object with id=1, Doctrine would not find it in the Symfony Bundle doing ...->find(1) until I added strategy

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this. It seems that Doctrine caches some of the mappings. I had just switched from a regular MongoId to a string id, Doctrine kept trying to convert my string id to a MongoID whenever I ran a query (as you described). This resulted in no results found.

I cleared all of my caches and that fixed it - Doctrine now just uses the regular string id.

I'm using the following:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="NONE", type="string")
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 2):

okay i got this solved with the following mapping

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string",name="_id")
 */
protected $idstring;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id2;
```

then idstring is the string representation